# Creating a boolean table comparing whether values within a column are recurring over similar values in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

what I'm trying to achieve is the following

I have df:

```
     Name      Type  Total paid
0    Amy     Jeans          62
1    Amy     Shirt          62
2    Amy     Shoes          62
3   Omar       Hat          25
4   Omar     Jeans          25
5  James       Hat          44
6  James  Bracelet          44
7  James     Jeans          44
8   Emma  Necklace          20
9   Emma     Shirt          20
```

And I'd like to generate df2 which is going to look like this:

```
    Name  Jeans  Shirt  Shoes    Hat  Bracelet  Necklace  Total paid
0    Amy   True   True   True  False     False     False          62
1   Omar   True  False  False   True     False     False          25
2  James   True  False  False   True      True     False          44
3   Emma  False   True  False  False     False      True          20
```

I have tried the stack function in pandas with no help, I've been stuck on this for a while now, any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `pd.crosstab`:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Type'], values=df['Total paid'],
                  aggfunc='max', 
                  margins=True, margins_name='Total_paid'
                 ).iloc[:-1]

out.iloc[:,:-1] = out.iloc[:,:-1].astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
Type   Bracelet   Hat  Jeans  Necklace  Shirt  Shoes  Total_paid
Name                                                            
Amy        True  True   True      True   True   True          62
Emma       True  True   True      True   True   True          20
James      True  True   True      True   True   True          44
Omar       True  True   True      True   True   True          25
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is very close but has a small issue with the final result. NaN is truthy so the final output is incorrect. One line of code will fix this by replacing NaN with 0 which evaluates to false.

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['type'], values=df['total_paid'],
                  aggfunc='max', 
                  margins=True, margins_name='total_paid'
                 ).iloc[:-1]

out.fillna(0,inplace = True)
out.iloc[:,:-1] = out.iloc[:,:-1].astype(bool)
out
```

Output:

```
type    Bracelet    Hat     Jeans   Necklace    Shirt   Shoes   total_paid
name                            
Amy     False       False   True    False       True    True    62
Emma    False       False   False   True        True    False   20
James   True        True    True    False       False   False   44
Omar    False       True    True    False       False   False   25
```